# Is there a possibility to know which biometric authentication the user used with the BiometricPrompt

Tags: java, android, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt

I want to know if in the onAuthenticationSucceeded() method it was possible to check which Biometric authentication method the user used. Not only if it was a weak or strong method but if they used facial recognition or fingerprint for example.

Here is my code:

```
    Executor executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context);
    BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt;
    BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo;
    biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(fragmentActivity, executor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationError(int errorCode, @NonNull CharSequence errString) {
            super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString);          
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(@NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
            System.out.println(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
            super.onAuthenticationFailed();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately not (as far as I am aware). I filed [an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111315641) about this years ago, but nothing seems to have come out of it so far.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will try to do it anyway, if I find a solution, I can post it here if anybody need it.

Comment: Hi @Axel, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Not yet sadly i don't work anymore on this project, sorry